# Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError in installing sass

Tags: sass, rubyinstaller

I'm beginner in sass and would like to install sass on window 10 then installed ruby installer and when I enter `gem install sass` command in command prompt I get the following error:

**Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.10.3.gem ( 22%)ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets https://api.rubygems.org/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3.gem**

[command prompt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSnSW.png)

I googled the error and couldn't resolve that and installed ruby installer in three different versions but every time enter `gem install sass` I get the same error.
Also in windows firewall the ruby interpreter has the public permission.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. when I created a system variable with name **RubyOpt** and value **rubygems** sass installed properly.